# How to accept request with port after domain in nginx

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, ip, http

I have a subdomain `https://test.shop.com`, I'm running a Nginx server and it's working fine. But I have to accept the request with `https://test.shop.com:8080/graphql/` and redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to the same machine. I've added this block

```
    location /graphql/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
```

But when I try to access `https://test.shop.com:8080/graphql/` from the browser it shows me **This site can’t be reached** seems something to do with dns. Although I can access `https://test.shop.com/graphql/` and it works fine.

My whole config file is

```
    server {
    server_name test.shop.com;
    root /var/www/html/test;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
      }
        # dashboard app
    location /dashboard/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /dashboard/index.html?$args;
    }

    location /graphql/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.shop.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.shop.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
    server {
    if ($host = test.shop.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.shop.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have the `graphql` URL reachable via another port, you need to have a separate `server` block:

```
server {
    listen 8080 ssl;

    ... ssl options ...

    location /graphql/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```